# Python Flask LDAP - can I see passwords as a developer?

Tags: python, flask, ldap, flask-login, python-ldap

Imagine a web application written using Python Flask for server-side processing that uses Flask-Login to handle user logins and python-LDAP to authenticate against an LDAP server.  A simple example of such an implementation is given here:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/flask-authentication-with-ldap--cms-23101

My question is:  how exactly is the password passed from the web form (client-side) back to the server and then passed on to the LDAP server for authentication?  More importantly, do I (as a developer of the application) have the ability to view a user's plain-text (or otherwise) password in this client-server transaction?

And if this authentication framework does allow a developer to view plaintext passwords from all the users of an application, then is there a way to allow my server-side processing to handle LDAP authentication that doesn't allow this or do I need to offload this functionality to the client?

Please let me know if I need to cross-post this on another SE forum.

Comment: in that setup, the application does see plaintext passwords. You can avoid this by using something that delegates to a third-party authentication service, like NTLM or OAuth.

Comment: care to elaborate on your first sentence?  Or provide reference to a source which would elaborate?

Comment: Flask-login sends the user name and password over SSL (if you configure it) but without other encryption or hashing. The app processes the plaintext password and usually sends this to the LDAP server to compare with the stored hash (some variants fetch hash from LDAP). I don't have a reference that supports this exact point, but it's basic stuff and you can verify yourself using a tool like TamperData

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification